# Hide or Remove DrawerToggle indicator/icon

Tags: android, xamarin, drawertoggle

I am working on xamrain android application.I am using **MvxActionBarDrawerToggle**.I am not able to hide/remove Drawer indicator/icon.
I have tried

```
 ((MainActivity)Activity).SupportActionBar.SetDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (false);
 ((MainActivity)Activity).SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (false);
 ((MainActivity)Activity).SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled (false);
 ((MainActivity)Activity).SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled (false);
 ((MainActivity)Activity).SupportActionBar.SetDisplayUseLogoEnabled (false);
 ((MainActivity)Activity).SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled (false);
```

but still I am not able to hide Drawer-Icon.How to hide/remove Drawer-Icon ?